# (eval (...)) in a flychecker command doesn't work with command symbols

Tags: emacs, elisp

[Flycheck](http://flycheck.lunaryorn.com/) is an emacs library that does background compilation of source files. You can add your own "checkers" (ways of compiling certain files) with help from the [manual](http://flycheck.lunaryorn.com/Extending.html#Definition).

I'm trying to add a compiler that needs to find a few files in a relative directory to the current file. I have a function that does that for me, called `(process filename)`. When building the terminal command to execute for a file, you can use an `(eval FORM)` compute parameters on the fly. Here's the relevant part of my checker's definition:

```
(flycheck-declare-checker unity-csharp-flychecker
  "given a c-sharp file, looks for the unity file and then tries to build it using mdtool."

  :command '("mdtool" "build" 
    (eval '(process source-original)))

  ...)
```

`source-original` is a special symbol that is substituted for buffer-file-name at execution time.

Unfortunately when I try to use the checker, I get this error:

```
Invalid result from evaluation of (quote (process source-original)): (process source-original)
```

Am I using `(eval)` incorrectly here? How can I get access to source-original from within so I can pass it to `(process)`? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the quote before process.

Comment: `Error: (void-variable source-original)` it's a different error - don't know if it's closer to the solution or not!

Comment: fwiw, `eval-expression` given `(eval (concat "bob" "pete"))` produces the same result as `(eval '(concat "bob" "pete"))`.

Comment: They produce the same result for different reasons. The first case evaluates the concat as a function, before eval ever looks at it. The second case evaluates the concat as part of eval.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct form:

```
(flycheck-declare-checker unity-csharp-flychecker
  "given a c-sharp file, looks for the unity file and then tries to build it using mdtool."

  :command '("mdtool" "build" 
    (eval (process buffer-file-name)))

  ...)
```

Thanks for Bruce Conner for getting me to remove the quote before `(process ...)`. That gave me a new error:

```
Error: (void-variable source-original)
```

So I dug into the source and saw there is no symbol substitution before evaluation. I assumed because we were given symbols that just using `buffer-file-name` wouldn't work, but I tried it and it does. I don't know if there are ramifications for that approach down the road.

Comment: Actually, I think the correct solution was just to quote the source-original symbol, could you give it a try?

Comment: I did try that first: `Wrong type argument: stringp, source-original`

Comment: Ok, then your answer is the best fix. And this source-original is probably an old method and you've spotted a documentation bug.

Comment: I can see other built-in checkers use it in the library, just not inside an eval. I've let the creator know to at least update the docs. Thanks for your help!